# Is "if winning isn't everything then why do they keep score" a correct sentence?

Tags: idioms, grammaticality, articles

We wanted to use this as a T-shirt quote, but I feel that "if winning isn't everything then why do they keep score" is wrong. The correct sentence should be "if winning isn't everything then why do they keep **a** score".
However, a [Google search](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Emc&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=if+winning+isnt+everything+then+why+do+they+keep+score&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) shows that I may be wrong. Only [one person](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Imc&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=%22if+winning+isnt+everything+then+why+do+they+keep+a+score%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) agrees with my sentence. Is the first sentence just incorrect American grammar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Keep score" is a (slightly) idiomatic expression that means "keeping track of the score".  It is not ungrammatical to use this phrase on a T-shirt (or anywhere else).  If the T-shirt had the text "keep a score", it might actually give the impression that the shirt was not made by a native English speaker.

(This is speaking as someone from the US; I don't know for certain if the expression might be different in the UK.)

Comment: BTW, note how there's no article in "to keep track", either.

Comment: Keep time, keep pace, keep tempo...

Comment: "Keep score, keep time, keep tempo, keep track" - aren't these the American short-forms of phrases? Like how aeroplane was shortened to airplane. I'm not from the UK, but I believe that since that's where English largely originated, UK English is the correct English. From that perspective, is "Keep score" correct or not (Note that in the sentence I've given, 'keep score' is the end of the sentence. If you used 'keep track' at the end of a sentence, would it still sound correct? It doesn't, to me )?

Comment: "...keep track of..." would be correct. I'm mostly exposed to UK English, and I've never heard of phrases like 'keep time', 'keep pace', 'keep tempo'. Grammatically, they sound very wrong. I'm open to corrections if I'm wrong...

Comment: @Rhodri: I've heard of "keeping pace", "keeping time" etc, but not "keep pace", "keep time" etc. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Nav: "I'm not from the UK, but I believe that since that's where English largely originated, UK English is the correct English."  I suppose, then, that West Germanic is even "more correct", since that is where English came from?  And Indo-European is even more correct than that?

Comment: Got it! 'keep score' sounds wrong because of the pronunciation of 'score' which comes immediately after 'keep'. The addition of 'a' as 'keep a score' eases the pronunciation in the same way as we use 'an' before any word that begins with a letter that sounds like a vowel. @Kosmonaut: I used the word 'largely' because I didn't want to shift from the topic of the original post. Although I do believe there's a reason for softwares to give 'UK English' and 'US English' as two separate options. Lets just say English always was and is a changing language. No boundaries.

Comment: @everyone: I recollect 'keep track', 'keep pace' and 'keep time' too. Although 'keep tempo' is something I haven't come across, but going with the pronunciation theory, I guess 'keep tempo' is also ok. I'll say, it's been nice to discuss this with you guys. Un-biased opinions on English from y'all are a refreshing change from the biased opinions I get to hear. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add the apostrophe to *isn't* and a question mark to the end, but there's really nothing wrong with putting such a sentence on a T-shirt. T-shirts and bumper stickers are pretty much exempt from formal rules, and no one expects them to be models of English grammar and usage anyway. I wouldn't worry about pleasing the editors on this one.

Comment: It's the "...keep a score..." part that I'm asking about. I'd like the English to be correct.

Comment: I respectfully disagree that this has anything to do with T-shirts. "To keep score" is perfectly correct English in my book.

Comment: I didn't see the "keep a score" part, and if that was your original question my eyes simply glossed over the "a" in it. It is normal to say "keep score," but there is nothing incorrect about saying "keep *a* score"; it sounds over-particular, however, and as it is better to try to state slogans in as few words as possible, I recommend taking the blue pencil to it.

Comment: @RegDwight: It has to do with T-shirts because the OP says it does in his first sentence. Given that constraint, I was curious why he thought there was anything wrong with the sentence (see my comment above concerning the superfluous article), but wanted to reassure him that he needn't worry.

Comment: It has to do with T-shirts in the sense that I want the correct English sentence to be on the T-shirt. I'm ok with casual English on T-shirts, but for this particular T-shirt, I wanted the right sentence. 'keep score' sounds wrong because it's at the end of the sentence. It may have sounded ok if it was "Did you keep score for that team?". Here, 'keep score' isn't at the end of the sentence, so somehow it sounds ok.

Answer (score 1):

Casual English is appropriate for a t-shirt since wearing clothing with phases on them is pretty casual. The term "keeping score" can have the meaning to keep track, but may a negative connotation of holding grudges.

Comment: What you mentioned is just one of the meanings of 'score'. http://www.google.co.in/search?q=define%3A+score&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: But you're very correct. I'd rather use 'keep a score' on the T-shirt, than allow anyone to think that it was meant in a negative way.